# RxJava - Request processing failed with IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using the RxJava and running into the following issue.

```
    threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0] with root cause
rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: [Ljava.lang.Object;.class
    at rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable.addValueAsLastCause(OnErrorThrowable.java:109) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwOrReport(Exceptions.java:190) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip.tick(OperatorZip.java:257) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorZip$Zip$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorZip.java:323) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onNext(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.onNext(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:53) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:92) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTimeoutBase$TimeoutSubscriber.onNext(OperatorTimeoutBase.java:131) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.producers.SingleDelayedProducer.emit(SingleDelayedProducer.java:102) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.producers.SingleDelayedProducer.setValue(SingleDelayedProducer.java:85) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromCallable.call(OnSubscribeFromCallable.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromCallable.call(OnSubscribeFromCallable.java:33) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:228) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.2.0.jar!/:1.2.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

The following is the snippet of what I'm trying to do with RxJava

```
    Observable<A> AObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() ->
            //External Service Call
    ).timeout(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
                LOGGER.warn(format("Server did not respond within %s ms for id=%s", 800, id));
                return null;
            });

    Observable<B> BObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() ->
            //External Service Call
    ).timeout(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .onErrorReturn( throwable -> {
                LOGGER.warn(format("Service did not respond within %s ms for id=%s", 800, Id));
                return null;
            });

    // Build Default response
    Observable<C> CObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() ->
            // Build Default one
    ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());


    return Observable.zip(AObservable, BObservable,CObservable,
            (AResponse, BResponse, CResponse) -> {

        // Handle response and combine them

    }).toBlocking().first();
```

I'm testing this locally and its working well but when I deploy it on the `aws` I run into the above-said issue. Also Please note that I'm not running into an issue for all the ids but only for few ids. I'm fairly new to `RxJava` could someone point out is there a potential issue with the async code.

Comment: Add `Observable.fromCallable()` code, in your current snippet there is no place for IndexOutOfBound, and stacktrace leads to `fromCallable()`

Comment: Do you want to return default response (CObservable) if either AObservable or BObservable return nulls?

Comment: @Dmitry, Yes that's right, you got me and that's the intention.

Comment: @Tuby I just use `Retrofit` as a `REST` client to get data from the external services which is running on the different domain. And here the downstream service calls are expected to return `A` and `B`.

Comment: Maybe try using Retrofit RxJava2CallAdapterFactory

Comment: Your zipper function crashes with that exception, RxJava just relays it back to the chain. You omitted that lambda body and the cause part of the exception which should point to the error in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `switchIfEmpty` operator to return default value when either of requests timeouts (thus returning empty observable).

```
Observable<String> AObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    return "response A";
}).timeout(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .onErrorResumeNext((value) -> {
            return Observable.empty();
        });

Observable<String> BObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    return "response B";
}).timeout(800, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .onErrorResumeNext((value) -> {
            return Observable.empty();
        });

Observable<String> CObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() -> "default response")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

String result = Observable.zip(AObservable, BObservable,
        (AResponse, BResponse) -> AResponse + " and " + BResponse)
        .switchIfEmpty(CObservable)
        .singleElement()
        .blockingGet();

System.out.println(result);
```

You can change `Thread.sleep` arguments to get different results.

Comment: I accepted this answer as its one of the way making sure that we are returning the default response when other services are timed out. Also, I fixed this issue by making the `zip` lambda body exception safe. @akarnokd comment led me to realise that the problem was with my `zip`